# Redirect in redux action using react-router-dom v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I'm trying to redirect user to '/' route in my redux action. But I can see that the route in the browser is changing but component does not render (it stays at the same view).

My action looks like that:

```
import history from '../../history';

export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  api.logout();
  // redirect
  history.push('/');

  dispatch({ type: TYPES.LOGOUT_USER });
};
```

My component with routes looks like that:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import history from './history';
import { Landing, AnotherComponent } from './views';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div className="main-container">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route path="/another_route" component={AnotherComponent} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And history.js file:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createHistory();
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Another option is to conditionally render the `<Redirect />` component from `react-router-dom` based on whatever store property you use to track authenticated status.

Answer (score 1):

If you use withRouter from react-router-dom in your component that triggers the logout call, you can pass the history to your action through the ownProps of mapDispatchToProps. Here is an example from one of my apps.

Component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    createTraining: training => dispatch(createTraining(training, ownProps)),
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TrainingDetailsPage));
```

My Thunk:

```
export function createTraining(training, ownProps) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return Api.createTraining(training).then(response => {
      ownProps.history.push('/trainings');
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) doesn't support `history` property. Try using the `history` object provided by react-router. Anything rendered directly from `Route` gets it as a property. For a deeply nested component you can use [withRouter HOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter). 
You will have to pass this history object to `logoutUser`.

[Sample code](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `history` import `Router` not `BrowserRouter` from the lib... Something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import history from './history';
import { Landing, AnotherComponent } from './views';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <div className="main-container">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route path="/another_route" component={AnotherComponent} />
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not enough rep to vote or comment, I just wanted to say that the answer provided by [Lee O.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815558/lee-o) works perfectly fine. I am using react-router-dom@5.2.0 with .

I just wanted to add one detail. You don't need to add the withRouter and the connect when exporting the component if the component in question is already inside a parent component that uses them.

Comment: Please wait until you have enough rep to add comments instead of adding comments answers.  It won't take long.